# Sfml Shader crash (Segmentation fault)

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, shader, sfml

Why does sf::Shader cause segmentation fault. I am going to show the code and I am telling to those that look the code that I use an engine and it works perfectly. So it doesn't cause the crash except with sf::Shader.And the code stops when I load the shader.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CoreEngine.h"
#include "maingame.h"

int main()
{
    //CoreEngine e(new MainGame(new Vector2i(800, 600), "Mama"));
    //e.start();
    Window::createWindow(800, 600, "Mama");
    Window::clearColor(124, 32, 125);

    bool running = true;

        sf::Shader shader;
    if(!shader.loadFromFile("fragment.fs", sf::Shader::Fragment))
        std::cout << "dfsfsdf";

    while(running){
        if(Window::isWindowClosed())
            running = false;


    sf::RectangleShape shape(sf::Vector2f(20, 20));
    shape.setPosition(10, 10);

        Window::clear();
        Window::getDrawer()->draw(shape, &shader);
        Window::render();
    }
}
```

Here is a compiling version of the code.
Use your own shader.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    //CoreEngine e(new MainGame(new Vector2i(800, 600), "Mama"));
    //e.start();
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "Msadama");

    sf::Shader shader;
    if(!shader.loadFromFile("fragment.fs", sf::Shader::Fragment)){
        std::cerr << "Shader failed to load" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    sf::RectangleShape shape(sf::Vector2f(20, 20));
    shape.setPosition(10, 10);
    while(window.isOpen()){
       sf::Event event;

       while(window.pollEvent(event)){
        if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
       }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }
}
```